# measure difference between rotation matrix

Tags: python, scipy, rotational-matrices

I have two rotation matrix
suppose initial basis O is identity in R^3 and
rotation RAO transforms a point in O into basis A and
rotation RBO transforms a point in O into basis B

I tried to calculate angle differences between RAO and RBO
like:

```
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation
def Rdiff(RAO, RBO):
    RBA = RAO.T @ RBO
    RBA = Rotation.from_matrix(RBA)
    return RBA.as_euler('zyx', degrees=True)

RAO = Rotation.from_euler('zyx', [10, 0, 13],                 
degrees=True).as_matrix()    
RBO = Rotation.from_euler('zyx', [0, 63, 40], 
degrees=True).as_matrix()

print(Rdiff(RAO, RBO))
```

but the result:

```
[-16.65056217  57.31794707  41.4856089 ]
```

is different from what I expected: [-10, 63, 26]
Is that something wrong here? How can I fix it?

[EDIT]
I used math formula from here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87338/change-in-rotation-matrix/87698#comment4515183_87698
and I have checked that RAO, RBO, RBA in function Rdiff is unitary.

[EDIT]
My original function in Rdiff is fault,
so I changed line:

```
RBA = RBO @ RAO.T
```

into

```
RBA = RAO.T @ RBO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems fine. The issue is that when you compose two rotations with given Euler angles, then you don't simply get a rotation given by the sums of these angles.

Comment: wow thank for clear explanation, It didn't occur to me. So If I want to measure two rotation matrix difference with respect to O, can I just compute  their Euler angle (from O) and just subtract these angle?

Comment: Wait but here still something wrong, I want to measure the angles between two rotation matrix but not a vector from O and transformed vector.

Comment: This is what I wrote: you are computing Euler angles of the RBO composed with the inverse of RAO. However,  these Euler angles are not just given by differences between the Euler angles of RBO and the Euler angles of RAO. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320981/how-to-get-euler-angles-with-respect-to-initial-euler-angle) is a discussion of a very similar question.